# Arranging $10$ Indians, $5$ Americans and $4$ Englishmen

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> In how many ways $10$ Indians, $5$ Americans and $4$ Englishmen can be seated in a row so that neither Americans nor Englishmen sit between Indians.

---

**Attempt at a solution:-**

**$1^{\text{st}}$ Attempt:-**

Since no Americans and Englishmen are to be seated between the Indians, so lets constraint the Indians to sit together and assume them to be a single entity. So, the total no of entities to be seated in a row become $5(\text{Americans})+4(\text{Englishmen})+1(\text{All Indians})=10$

So, total ways in which these entities can be permuted along a row= $P_{10}^{10}=10!$

But, since we had only assumed all the Indians to be one entity but since they are different, so they need to be arranged among themselves too.

So the total ways of arranging the Indians, Americans and Englishmen according to the problem statement $=10!\cdot 10!$

**$2^{\text{nd}}$ Attempt:-**

The firs attempt was the standard way of doing this. But I thought of doing this with the help of generating functions, as you will see below.

Consider the following arrangement of Indians and spaces between them:-

$$x_1\;\;\text I_1\;\;x_2\;\;\text I_2\;\;x_3\;\;\text I_3\;\;x_4\;\;\text I_4\;\;x_5\;\;\text I_5\;\;x_6\;\;\text I_6\;\;x_7\;\;\text I_7\;\;x_8\;\;\text I_8\;\;x_9\;\;\text I_9\;\;x_{10}\;\text I_{10}\;\;x_{11}$$

So, we get the following equation to solve

$$\sum_{i=1}^{11}{x_i}=9$$

Assuming Englishmen and Americans as identical for solving the equation.

We have the following conditions to take into consideration too 
$$0\le x_1,x_{11}\le 8\\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\; 0 \le x_r \le 9\;,\qquad r=\{2,3,4,5,\ldots ,10\}$$

So, we have the following generating function in which we have to find the coefficient of $x^9$

$$\begin{aligned}
&\text{coefficient of $x^9$}(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^8)^2(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^9)^9\\
=&\text{coefficient of $x^9$}\left(\frac{1-x^9}{1-x}\right)^2\left(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\right)^9\\
=&\text{coefficient of $x^9$}(1-x)^{-11}\\
=&\binom{11+9-1}{9}=\binom{19}{9}
\end{aligned}$$

Now, since the Englishmen and Americans are distinct despite assuming them to be indistinguishable and the Indians can be arranged among themselves, we get the total ways to be

$$\binom{19}{9}\cdot 10!\cdot 9!=19!\text{(which is the total ways of arranging without any restriction)}$$

---

**My deal with the question:-**

In my $2^{\text{nd}}$ attempt I think that the way that I assumed the range of values of $x_1, x_{11}$ is creating the problem. If that is not so, I don't know what is it that is going wrong here, and if it so happens that the range of values of $x_1,x_{11}$ is creating the problem then also I am not able to come up with the right thing to do.

Also, I know that an alternative approach for this method (using generating functions) would have been assigning the range as follows

$$0\le x_1,x_{11}\le 9\\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad  x_r=0 \;,\qquad \qquad \qquad r=\{2,3,4,5,\ldots ,10\}$$

But that would have been same as my $1^{\text{st}}$ Attempt

Comment: Ah, combinatorics. The topic allowing the most racist sounding problems to be set. :)

Comment: @Deepak - Yeah...I wanted to convert them to Person belonging to type P or something like that, but I let it be after seeing many such questions. But gotta tell you you took the words right outta my mouth.

Comment: @Deepak Are the Indians distinguishable, or do they all look the same?

Comment: I think the problem implies that the americans are not distinguishable among themselves, nor the english, nor the indians, otherwise we could immediately replace the problem with that of 10 indians and 9 americans. The *sit between indians* part is ambiguous, can you explain precisely what it means ?

Comment: @Arthur Hilarious (meant unironically). To get into the spirit of this repartee, I was thinking of replying "only by smell" or something else of similarly dubious taste, but I often find myself unable to discern the line between clever and crass, so I'll stop here. Suffice it to say that I find this sort of question phrasing to be extremely injudicious.

Comment: @Gribouillis I think all the people are distinguishable individually the only thing that makes them fall in one category is whether they are indians Americans or Englismen. Also why would you convert the Englishmen into Americans while replacing the problem.

Comment: @user350331 Because if the Americans are distinguishable, and the Englishmen are distinguishable, then they are nine distingiushable persons, and there is no need for nationality to enter this whole thing at all.

Comment: @Deepak that was [probably a wise choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe's_law). One can never be sure how one is interpreted over the internet.

Comment: @Arthur That was funny....but if it was a serious comment on the question I was not able to make sense out of it, because if the nationality distinguishes them then the arrangement changes. And I did not know there was a law regarding humor posts.

Comment: I apologize for my english being far from perfect. I don't see any racist connotation in the problem. On the other hand I'd like to have an explanation about the *sit between indians*.

Comment: @Gribouillis - I'm wondering if it means no American or English sits between an indian either side, but you could have 'Indian American English Indian', but not Inidian american Indian

Comment: @Gribouillis As I tried to solve it in my second attempt based on the first attempt I think the problem says that the number of Englishmen and Americans between the Indians can be anywhere from 0 to 9. But I have some doubts regarding the people that can sit besides the Indian sitting in the extreme position.

Comment: @Deepak could you explain the concern to me? I agree that another formulation might be better, but I do not see what is racist about it.

Comment: @quid I would consider it insensitive to talk about seating people so that people of a certain ethnicity don't have to be seated adjacent to (or in between) people of a certain other ethnicity. Considering there are numerous perfectly analogous formulations of this sort of problem, why even bring race, ethnicity or national origin into it?

Comment: Sorry, I was rushing: that should have read "numerous perfectly inoffensive analogous formulations".

Comment: @Deepak thank you for the clarification. Should we edit the question?

Comment: @quid It's fine, thanks. It's a nice "proof of concept". :)

Comment: What about the american indians? :P